# Как добавить смайлы в android приложение

Tags: android

Собственно необходимо добавить смайлы в `android` приложение в поля `EditText` и `RecyclerView` 
Есть ли существующие библиотеки?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Библиотека не нужна. Смайлы, которые у вас доступны в телефоне закодированы в UNICODE. Все что нужно, это перевести правильно юникод(`int`) в строку. Вот [ресурс](http://apps.timwhitlock.info/emoji/tables/unicode) на все смайлы с Unicode.

Перевод юникода в строку-смайл (код на котлине)

```
fun getEmojiByUnicode(unicode: Int): String = String(Character.toChars(unicode))
```

Если юникод приходит в виде строки, то можно перевести его в `int` так:

```
Integer.parseInt("юникод без превикса U+", 16)
```

Answer (score 2):

Хотя ответ Павла весьма корректен и точен (я проголосовал за него), позволю себе чуть больше его расширить:

Замените из этой таблицы http://apps.timwhitlock.info/emoji/tables/unicode 'U+' на '0x'.
Например `'U+1F60A'` на `'0x1F60A'`.

Таким образом, вы получите int

```
int unicode = 0x1F60A;
```

Затем, можно сделать вот такой метод:

```
public String getEmojiByUnicode(int unicode){
    return new String(Character.toChars(unicode));
}
```

В TextView (или в EditText) вы увидите  без Drawable

Answer (score 0):

```
    // Create spannable text and set style.
Spannable text = new SpannableString("This is underline and bold text.");
text.setSpan(new UnderlineSpan(), 8, 17, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
text.setSpan(new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD), 22, 26, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

// Set spannable text in TextView.
TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
textView.setText(text);
```

http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/theory/spannable.php